# An animation tool to explain my software project visually

Tags: flash, animation

I have a software project, which involves complex process and calculation. Rather than writing it's logic and business flow in a document, i want it to be explained in some sort of animation visually, which would be easier for some one new to my project.

Can someone put forward some suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps the mere fact that it needs a complex animation to be explained is the symptom of a bad design or architecture.

Comment: I am not going to explain the way the software  is designed. I just want to explain the Business flow behind it.

Comment: Did you consider making *simple* schemas (e.g. with http://projects.gnome.org/dia/ ...)? Perhaps several of them?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, explain your thing with some simple schema, not a complex animation.

Even complex software like compilers can be explained with simple figures. You can use a vectorial drawing software like [dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) or [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) to make them.

Prefer several figures, perhaps one "zooming" into parts of a previous one, to a complex animation. Explain these figures with short sentences.

People should be able to read your document on paper, in a plane, train, car  without a laptop; so a flash animation is probably not appropriate to explain software architecture or business logic.

If you have too much time, use flash for tutorial material.